# Maximun vertical distance beween$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \:and\:\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

To calculate the maximun vertical distance beween$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \:and\:\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ at a point x=a, where a>1
I proceeded as follows:
$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\right|=\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x\sqrt{x}}
\\since f(x)=\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x\sqrt{x}}
\\f'(x)=\frac{\left(3-x\right)}{2x^{\frac{5}{2}}}
\\this\: function\: has\: a\: maximum\: at\: f'(x)=0
\\I\: got\: x=3$
So the two curves have a maximum distance at x=3

Now my question is, am I right?

Comment: You probably should also prove that this point is really a maximum, not minimum (though the statement of the task implicitly implies that).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to prove that is a local maximum. You also have to mention that in the point x=1 the functions don't are at maximum vertical distance (because if the point is on the border it could be a local maximum and thus a global maximum, but without having null derivative). Also, you have to prove that the derivative is negative beyond the maximum, thus proving that the function decreases, it could be that the function is unbounded and there is not maximum vertical difference, and that would not imply derivative being null in any place.

Comment: The function has a domain of [0, ∞)& a range of (-∞, 3). Is positively sloped at x<3 and negatively sloped at x>3. So it has an absolute max at x=3

Answer (score 0):

You must also investigate the end points. At $a=1$ they are both equal = 1 and as $x \rightarrow \infty$ both become 0. So if the only solution to derivative = 0 is the point you mentioned and the functions are differentiable everywhere, then you can be sure that it must be a maximum.